# Android Studio java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

Hello I am trying to make an application using intents however whenever I want to use the work method it will print an error. I am a beginner to Android So I have no clue how to fix it

**The Error :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.CallActivity } from ProcessRecord{27530cd6 1787:edgaraxe.com.smartad/u0a58} (pid=1787, uid=10058) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2395)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1480)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
            at edgaraxe.com.smartad.SecondPage.Work(SecondPage.java:44)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372
```

The method causing the issue :

```
public void Work (View view) {
    SharedPreferences share = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_TITLE, 0);
    String asd = share.getString("phone", "Phone not found");
    System.out.println(asd);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+asd));
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

The complete code can be found here : http://pastebin.com/mAhxUVDC

Comment: add in your `manifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

Comment: Please include the stacktrace in the question. Pastebin like sites are really meant for too many lines of code that couldn't be added here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look further down in your error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.CallActivity } from ProcessRecord{27530cd6 1787:edgaraxe.com.smartad/u0a58} (pid=1787, uid=10058) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

You need to go to your project setup and add the permission "CALL_PHONE". if you don't know how to add permissions, take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.CallActivity } from ProcessRecord{27530cd6 1787:edgaraxe.com.smartad/u0a58} (pid=1787, uid=10058) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

You must add to your AnrdoidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a permission declaration in your AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```